# Where can I find Android Tab Icons

Tags: android, icons, android-tabhost

Does anybody know of a website where I can find Android TabHost icons? (free or paid)

Comment: Is this really programming related?

Comment: Programmers in general are not always good graphic designers. However they rely heavily on graphics to make good applications. In this way, easily finding useful graphics is indeed related to programming in my opinion...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Anyone who is looking for Android tab icons, or any android icons, should definitely check out this website. I found it super helpful.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: Annoying that it doesn't work in Opera, Safari or Firefox (Chrome only), but otherwise very useful.

Comment: Just WOW! Saves so much of time :O !!!!

Comment: That link is not working

Answer (score 8):

Also there are several Drawables that can be reused from android.jar.

This website catalogs them with their names:
http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

There are a bunch of good ones for use with tabs.

Comment: These are on your computer, if you have the Android SDK installed. Go to the SDK directory, go into `platforms/`, pick an Android version (e.g., `android-8/`), then go into `data/res/`. You will find the icons in `drawable-hdpi/` and `drawable/mdpi/`.

Comment: I looked in the folder and found the icon I wanted ic_menu_refresh but when I tried to set it using setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh it didn't resolve?? I assume it's bad practice to physically copy the icons to my drawable folder?

Comment: @Bear Google actually recommends copying the icons into your drawable folder since the Android graphic may differ from device to device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html#examples5

Answer (score 4):

Check out [glyFX](http://www.glyfx.com) we have a couple of android tab bar icon sets, are working on more and can do custom ones if need be.

Answer (score 3):

Here you will find icons for the android menus for free: http://www.androidicons.com/ But, you can contact them and pay for custom icons for your tabs.

Answer (score 3):

lots of links to icons here:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/

Answer (score 2):

look for android tab icons here:
http://www.aha-soft.com/stock-icons/android-tab-icons.htm

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout a new set of 350 Android Menu and Tab Bar Icons. http://www.billybarker.net/350-mobile-app-icons-for-developers/

Answer (score 0):

There is a large set (550+) of [Android tab and menu icons](http://www.iconsberlin.com/) at iconsberlin.com available. Cross platform developers may get iOS and Android icons in one package.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other sites too providing you free icons.

http://ntt.cc/2010/08/04/350-fresh-and-elegant-free-icons-for-android.html.
http://www.download3000.com/download_63177.html